# 1004 Global Error - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, range, cells

My code doesn't work. I want to do `A2 + 1 = A3` in macros, but when I tried to using p as integer, it gives me `1004 Global Error`. **How to do `(n,1) A2 + 1 = A3` in Excel VBA?**

```
Sub agregarproducto()

Range("A7:G7").Select
Range("G7").Activate
Selection.Copy

Dim p As Integer

p = 0
p = Range("A2:A50").Count
p = p + 1

Range(p, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Range("E2:E3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("L11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Range(p, 1).Select
```

to

```
Cells(p, 1).select
```

Comment: `p` is assigned `p = Range("A2:A50").Count`. Shouldn't that make it `Cells(p, 1)` ? Or even `Cells(p + 1, 1)` since p is the Count and starts at row 2?